# Is there a way to allow user to select multiple photos and videos using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, video, camera, photo

I am coding a cross-platform app and am working on the part where if the user clicks the button, the code shows the user's phone gallery showing both images and videos and the user can choose multiple images or videos. I didn't know how to approach this problem so I used `MediaPicker` but realized I can't choose multiple images or videos nor I can make the images and the videos show up on the same page. Since MediaPicker has `PickPhotoAsync` and `PickVideoAsync` separately, I don't think there is a way to show both the photos and the videos at the same page using MediaPicker. And because they have different functions to pick a photo or a video I had to code like the following:

`var action = await DisplayActionSheet("Select media type", "Cancel", null, "Photo", "Video");`

and make the user choose whether if they want to select photos or videos. Is there a way or a library that allows the user to see both photos and videos at the same page without asking whether to pick photos or videos and also allows the user to select multiple of them? I need to eventually get the images or the videos the user selected and turn each of them into byte and add them to the byte list so later I can bring them up when I need to.

Comment: https://www.xamboy.com/2019/03/12/select-multiple-images-and-videos-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I saw that article before and wanted to know if there is a way to do that in the Main code and not in each Android and iOS project. I have a code that takes photos and upload photos in the Main project so it would be inconvenient to add different codes in different platform.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if there is. Next time you write a question, if you've found a link that almost does what you want, please add it to the question, and explain what you are hoping for instead. This will be helpful both in answering your question, and future readers might decide the link does what they want. Thanks!

Comment: MediaPicker is open source, you are free to modify it to suit your needs

Answer (score 1):

MediaPicker not supports multiple select. So you need to use dependency service for each platform to implement it.

For android, you can check this article about [Select multiple images from the gallery in Xamarin Forms](https://medium.com/swlh/select-multiple-images-from-the-gallery-in-xamarin-forms-df2e037be572).

For IOS, you can check this nuget package [GMImagePicker.Xamarin](https://github.com/roycornelissen/GMImagePicker.Xamarin) or you can use the service in the ios.

Here is the sample of the project [MultiImagePicker](https://github.com/danielkon96/MultiImagePicker).